# Problem with Regular expression for getting substring in colon-delimited data

Tags: .net, regex

I am using a regular expression which gets the substring associated with a match
i.e

```
"(MAC:[A-Z0-9]{12})"
```

This regex will find the occurences of MAC:(Some characters) in a string.
This regex is working for characters less than 10 i.e

```
 "(MAC:[A-Z0-9]{8})"   -   WORKS

but,

 "(MAC:[A-Z0-9]{8})"   -   THROWS EXCEPTION
```

Any help appreciated regarding the same.

**EDIT**: I use something like this:

```
MatchCollection macName = Regex.Matches(otherdata,
                                        @"(MAC:[A-Z0-9]{10})+",
                                        RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
```

To extract the characters after MAC:

```
"ADMIN:1EXT:0NOR:0OUT:1PRI:1BAT:1MOD:1MAC:BFEBFBFF000006FB00:1E:37:54:AE:C8"
```

I should get the string after using the regex:

```
MAC:BFEBFBFF000006FB00:1E:37:54:AE:C8
```

I hope I have explained myself clearly.

Comment: Are you trying to match all characters after "MAC:..."? Or those less that ten?

Comment: We need to see some actual code.  And it would help to know what exception it's throwing, and when.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
"(MAC:[A-Z0-9]{12})+"
```

Answer (score 0):

Or this one:

```
"(MAC:[\d\w:]+?[\d\w:]*)"
```

This one makes additional check to be sure that this is good match.